# Why my AJAX code is unable to get data from php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to see whether a particular name I entered is on the list or not. And I want the response in XML. I've tried whatever I could but not getting the result. (I'm using firefox by the way).

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing ajax!</h1>
<form onsubmit="changer('inputing')">
enter name <input type="text" id="inputing" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<p id="ch">enter name to check</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function changer(a) {
var mo = new XMLHttpRequest();
var qry = document.getElementById(a).value;
mo.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(mo.readyState == 4 && mo.status == 200) {
var res = mo.responseXML;
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = res.firstChild.nodeValue;
}
}
mo.open("GET", "appr.php?name=" + qry, true);
mo.send(null);
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo "<cover>";
$b = array("sam", "norton", "maya", "sijosh", "noor", "timothy");
$c = $_GET["name"];

if(in_array($c, $b)) {
echo "he is here";
}
else { echo "sorry... we dont know him"; }
echo "</cover>";

?>
```

Comment: Need to prevent default form submit so page doesn't reload

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't see what is happening as the form gets submitted the non-ajax / regular way as well.

You can avoid that by using for example:

```
<form action='' onsubmit="changer('inputing'); return false;">
```

Although ideally you would get rid of the inline javascript altogether and handle everything in a javascript event handler.

Comment: Thank you sir... It almost solved the problem, so I think. Because, the paragraph content, which is supposed to be changed, is disappearing completely. Is there a problem with parsing the XML data from the AJAX object?

Comment: @ManuSoman You should check the console to see what you get back. But if you want to pass information from php to javascript you really should use json instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well at last I figured it out! There were two problems. First one was that the page was getting refreshed every time I submit the form, as you guys said. I corrected it. The second problem was in the parsing of XML data. I transferred the XML to the variable 'res' but after that I had to get the 'documentElement' from the XML. So I added another variable 'xmlde'.

```
xmlde = res.documentElement;
```

Then,

```
document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = xmlde.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Problem was solved!